# Session variable not being set in the first time

Tags: php, session

My modal for asking name

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div class="modal name fade modal-scrollable" id="name" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <h4 class="modal-title myModalLabel">Your name!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="nameForm" action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Your name : </label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control name" name="name" required/>

        </div>
    </div></div><br/><br/>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ok">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Script code

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['user']['name']){
echo "<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#name').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: true
})
        $('#name').modal('show');
    });
</script>";
}
?>

<script>
$('#ok').submit(function(){
<?php
$_SESSION['user']['name']=$_POST['name'];
print"location.reload();";
?>
});
</script>
```

This code actually works fine. The code is that on page load it will ask the name of user and set the session variable to set the entered name. It will open the modal only if session variable is not set. But in reality the user has to enter his name twice.I even tried reload() but it didnt work. Please help!

Comment: Where's your `session_start()`?

Comment: Its there! In the starting of my code!

Comment: You mean it's there since 3 mins ago when you added it...

Comment: Also, unless both of those code examples are in the same file, you need one at the top of the PHP script too.

Comment: It is there in my original file! Forgot to write it here! You mean to say i need to have it twice in the same file?

Comment: No, you don't need it in the same file more than once usually, and you shouldn't call it more than once per request (would raise a notice).

Answer (score 0):

Your session is being set correctly. However, you are not initializing the session. The first line after your `<?php` tag should be:

```
session_start();
```

Please, also note that in this part of your code, you should print your JavaScript code:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['user']['name']=$_POST['name'];
print "location.reload();";
?>
```

Comment: Still it asks twice for the name!

Comment: That might the reason of the fact that you are not using isset() function to check if the $_SESSION has been set before. Try if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['name'])){ on your first if Statement @SaranshSeth

Comment: Did that! Doesnt make difference!

Comment: Did you add session_start() in your php file aswell? I can only see it on your html file..., what btw, is not usefull at all in that code @SaranshSeth

Comment: Emmm, okei. Please, edit your post and show us the complete webpage as a whole. @SaranshSeth